# Define custom PHP classes to use in CodeCeption tests

Tags: php, codeception, web-api-testing

I'm new in CodeCeption and I've started with a few simple API test cases. I wanted to create my own classes in order to manage my methods in multiple files. I have written a new PHP file named `MyClass.php` in directory `_support` which has a class named `MyClass` inside.

```
<?php
class MyClass extends \Codeception\Actor
{
    use _generated\ApiTesterActions;
    public  function  SayHi($name) {
        $respBody = [
            'hi' => 'hi' + $name
        ];
        return json_decode($respBody, true) ;
    }
}
```

I have added this class in my dependencies in file `codeception.yml`:

```
modules:
    enabled:
        - MyClass
```

I also added MyClass as the `actor` in `api.suite.yml`:

```
actor: MyClass
```

I tried to build the project in order to have access to the mentioned class in my tests, but it couldn't find the module:

```
zeinab@Zeinab:~/PhpstormProjects/api-testing$ php vendor/bin/codecept build
Building Actor classes for suites: acceptance, api, functional, unit

In ModuleContainer.php line 80:

  Module MyClass could not be found and loaded  


build
```

Is there anything that I've missed?

I have previously added this module in class `ApiTester` in file `ApiTester.php` and it worked fine; I could build the project and use the method in tests.

**EDIT 1:**

I have changed my code and configurations based on @Alexey and @Naktibalda help notes.

This is my file structure now:

```
test
|_ src
   |_ MyClass.php
|_ tests
   |_ ...
   |_ mytests
      |_ MyCest.php
   |_ ...
   |_ mytests.suite.yml
   |_ ...
|_ vendor
|_ codeception.yml
|_ composer.json
|_ composer.lock
```

This is my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "codeception/base": "^2.5",
        "ext-json": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Codeception\\Module\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

This code is inside `MyClass.php`:

```
<?php
class MyClass extends \Codeception\Actor
{
    public function SayHi($name) {
        $respBody = 'hi' . $name;
        return json_decode($respBody, true) ;
    }
}
```

This code is inside `MyCest.php`:

```
<?php
class MyCest
{
    public function MyTestCase(MyClass $I)
    {
        $I->SayHi('ZiZi');
    }
}
```

This is inside `mytests.suite.yml`:

```
actor: ApiTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - REST:
        depends: PhpBrowser
        part: Json

    - Asserts:
```

Now, build is OK and its logs implying `mytests` has been successfully loaded as a suite:

```
zeinab@Zeinab:~/PhpstormProjects/test$ codecept build
==== Redirecting to Composer-installed version in vendor/codeception ====
Building Actor classes for suites: acceptance, api, functional, mytests, unit
 -> AcceptanceTesterActions.php generated successfully. 0 methods added
\AcceptanceTester includes modules: PhpBrowser, \Helper\Acceptance
 -> ApiTesterActions.php generated successfully. 0 methods added
\ApiTester includes modules: \Helper\Api
 -> FunctionalTesterActions.php generated successfully. 0 methods added
\FunctionalTester includes modules: \Helper\Functional
 -> ApiTesterActions.php generated successfully. 0 methods added
\ApiTester includes modules: REST, PhpBrowser, Asserts
 -> UnitTesterActions.php generated successfully. 0 methods added
\UnitTester includes modules: Asserts, \Helper\Unit
```

But running tests encounters an error:

```
zeinab@Zeinab:~/PhpstormProjects/test$ codecept run tests/mytests/MyCest.php 

==== Redirecting to Composer-installed version in vendor/codeception ====
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.5.1
Powered by PHPUnit 7.5.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Running with seed: 


Mytests Tests (1) -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E MyCest: My test case (0.00s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEPRECATION: Calling the "Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client::getInternalResponse()" method before the "request()" one is deprecated since Symfony 4.1 and will throw an exception in 5.0. /home/zeinab/PhpstormProjects/test/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Client.php:217


Time: 76 ms, Memory: 12.00MB

There was 1 error:

---------
1) MyCest: My test case
 Test  tests/mytests/MyCest.php:MyTestCase

  [InjectionException] Failed to inject dependencies in instance of 'MyCest'. Class MyClass does not exist  

#1  phar:///usr/local/bin/codecept/autoload.php:12
#2  /usr/local/bin/codecept:5

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

I think I still  have problem in configuring my `composer.json`, but I can't figure it out.

**EDIT 2:**

I changed my class definition in `composer.json` to ``; the result was:

```
zeinab@Zeinab:~/PhpstormProjects/test$ codecept run tests/mytests/MyCest.php 

==== Redirecting to Composer-installed version in vendor/codeception ====
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.5.1
Powered by PHPUnit 7.5.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
Running with seed: 


Mytests Tests (1) ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E MyCest: My test case (0.00s)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEPRECATION: Calling the "Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client::getInternalResponse()" method before the "request()" one is deprecated since Symfony 4.1 and will throw an exception in 5.0. /home/zeinab/PhpstormProjects/test/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Client.php:217


Time: 76 ms, Memory: 12.00MB

There was 1 error:

---------
1) MyCest: My test case
 Test  tests/mytests/MyCest.php:MyTestCase

  [InjectionException] Failed to inject dependencies in instance of 'MyCest'. Class MyClass does not exist  

#1  phar:///usr/local/bin/codecept/autoload.php:12
#2  /usr/local/bin/codecept:5

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

Comment: File structure in Edit 1 shows mistake in the filename - `MyClassh.php`

Comment: @Naktibalda, it was my typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue; thanks to @Alexey and @Naktibalda.

I put PHP file containing my class, `MyClass.php`, in directory `src/` and defined my class in `composer.json` as:

```
{
    "require": {
        "codeception/base": "^2.5",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "codeception/codeception": "^2.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": ["src/"]
    }
}
```

This is my file structure now:

```
test
|_ src
   |_ MyClass.php
|_ tests
   |_ ...
   |_ mytests
      |_ MyCest.php
   |_ ...
   |_ mytests.suite.yml
   |_ ...
|_ vendor
|_ codeception.yml
|_ composer.json
|_ composer.lock
```

This code is inside `MyClass.php`:

```
<?php
class MyClass extends \Codeception\Actor
{
    public function SayHi($name) {
        $respBody = 'hi' . $name;
        return $respBody;
    }
}
```

This code is inside `MyCest.php`:

```
<?php
class MyCest
{
    public function MyTestCase(MyClass $I)
    {
        $resp = $I->SayHi('ZiZi');
        echo "Response: " . $resp;
    }
}
```

This is inside `mytests.suite.yml`:

```
actor: ApiTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - REST:
        depends: PhpBrowser
        part: Json

    - Asserts:
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to code a Helper first? In this case extend your class from `\Codeception\Module`, not `\Codeception\Actor`? Leave then your config as is and remove adding it as an Actor

Comment: If I define it as a `Helper`, I won't be able to use `ApiTesterActions` inside of it; which I'm actually willing to do.

Comment: Then try to make sure you add autoload section to your composer.json of your module with the path to MyClass

Comment: Since I'm new to CodeCeption, would you please say if `"autoload": { "MyClass": ["_support/MyClass.php"] }` is a correct configuration or not?

Comment: it's more composer documentation, not codeception, but have a look at this tutorial: https://jordaneldredge.com/blog/writing-a-custom-codeception-module/ , you still need to extend \Codeception\Module class in your module class and you need to add `"autoload: {"psr-4": "Codeception\\Module\\": "src"}"` and put your class into `src` directory in your module folder, not into `_support`

Comment: Instead of using ApiTesterActions, call methods of other modules by using `getModule` method, e.g.: `$this->getModule('REST')->sendGet('/');`

Comment: @Naktibalda and Alexey, would you two please review my edits on the question?

Comment: I think it tries to load `MyClass` from root namespace as you never defined it neither in use in MyTest nor in the namespace of MyClass, but you registered only `Codeception\Module\ ` namespace in composer autoloader, so it tries to look for MyClass in the root namespace and can't find it. What if you change your composer json `autoload` section to `"psr-4": {  "": "src/"   }`?